# TypeError: an integer is required in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame column, named date with the following values:

```
         date
0    201801010000
1    201801010050
2    201801010150
3    201801010250
4    201801010300
5    201801010350
6    201801010450
7    201801010550
8    201801010600
9    201801010650
```

I want to convert it to date and time, so I used the following code:

```
df2['date'] = pd.datetime(df2['date'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

But, its giving me an error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I thought that I need to convert the column into integer so, I converted it as:

```
df2["date"] = df2.date.astype(int)
```

But, still I am getting the same error. Could anyone tell me why am I getting the error?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['GMT'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d%H%M')`

Comment: @cs95 Its giving me error `KeyError: 'GMT'`

Comment: That is literally the column name you've pasted in your question. Replace "GMT" with "date", or whatever. It's your data.

Comment: @cs95 After using the code as you mentioned, I am getting different error  `ValueError: Buffer has  wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2) `

Comment: The fix would be: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d%H%M', errors='coerce')`

Comment: @cs95 After using the code my data type is still object, shouldn't it be converted to dtype: datetime64 as https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html ?

Comment: It will be, if you assign it back to a column.

Comment: Not required, I've given you all the information you need to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: I have assigned it as `df2['date']=pd.to_datetime(df2['date'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d%H%M',errors='coerce')`, but it is still an object datatype